# Electric power steering column noise

Tags: power-steering

I have a 2014 Honda Accord coupe equipped with Electric Power Steering (EPS). When cranking the steering wheel, I can hear a noise coming from the steering column, mostly at slow speed like backing out of a parking spot. It's not overly noisy, but I certainly never noticed any noise coming from the steering column with hydraulic power steering. The noise is kind of a rattling noise, sort of like a loose or improperly lubricated bearing. At first I thought this was just something common to EPS and nothing to be concerned about, but I'm beginning to wonder if I should have it looked at. I have not taken the car to the dealer yet, for fear that they will just tell me it's normal and tell me to go away. Opinions?
**Edit:** I took the car in to the Honda dealer. They think (are pretty sure) that the noise is coming from the SRS cable reel.
I did a quick Google search, and it looks like the part can be a problem. If it seizes and the cable breaks (it's just a thin, flat ribbon cable coiled up inside), you can lose all the steering wheel controls (cruise, volume, air bag, etc).
I'm glad I'm having it looked at while the car is still under warranty. I will post the final outcome.

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance that the pinion of the power steering assistance motor has worn off . It is enclosed in a complete assembly which is located just behind the dash board ! [image: power steering mechanism]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The car was purchased brand new and has made that sound since its first day. I'm going to have the dealer take a look at it.

Comment: Honda tests cars very well before delivery! It is a great chance that the noise you hear is normal ! My car also makes a sound at low speeds ! But if the sound is well audible , then it is a matter of concern!

Answer (score 1):

I just got my car back from the dealer, and it turns out the noise I was hearing in the steering column was coming from the cable reel rubbing against the cable reel bracket. Honda is aware of the problem and has a redesigned bracket that addresses the issue. The redesigned bracket gives the cable reel a bit more room to rotate in without it rubbing against the bracket. Eventually, the cable reel would probably jam against the bracket causing the ribbon cable to snap, which would disable all steering wheel electronics including the air bag and horn.
I'm glad I had it looked at. The steering column is now completely silent.